# React: Mapping children of a parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

So I want to add certain styles to any child that's appended to a component. Let's say the parent component  is called `Section` and children are called `Card`in this case. in `Section.js` I am trying this: -

```
renderChildren = () =>{
  return React.Children.map(this.props.children, (child, i)=>{
    let el = React.cloneElement(child,{
      style: {opacity:0.5}
    })
    return el
  })
}

render(){
  <ScrollView>
       {this.renderChildren()}
   </ScrollView>
}
```

The above approach doesn't work for me. And I would like to know why. Also is there a way where I could map across the children and wrap them in a new component? Something like this;

```
this.props.children.map(Child => <Wrapper> <Child/> </Wrapper> )
```

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

To wrap your children into a wrapper just put the call to `React.Children.map` into the wrapper component:

```
const OpaqueWrapper = ({ children }) => (
    // check that children is defined 
    // if you do not want your wrapper to be rendered empty
    children && (
        <Wrapper>
            {React.Children.map(children, child => (
                React.cloneElement(child, {style: {...child.props.style, opacity: 0.5}})
            ))}
        </Wrapper>
    )
);
```

Also note that you have to merge the styles provided to the original child with the styles injected or you will lose the ability to style the children at all.

[See this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/oj8oky8vy6) for a working example.

As to why it did not work in your code: Are you sure that your `<Card>` component does handle the `style` prop correctly, i.e. applying it to it's children?

**EDIT**:

> The sloution wraps all children components in a single wrapper, but I
>   would like to wrap each child with the applied wrapper , as shown in
>   my question.

The just move the wrapper into `React.Children.map`:

```
const OpaqueWrapper = ({ children }) => (        
    React.Children.map(children, child => (
       <Wrapper>
           {React.cloneElement(child, {style: {...child.props.style, opacity: 0.5}})}
       </Wrapper>
    )))
);
```

Comment: The sloution wraps all children components in a single wrapper, but I would like to wrap each child with the applied wrapper , as shown in my question.

Comment: @AnishK. Well then just put the `<Wrapper>` into the call to `React.Children.map`. If have updated my answer as well as the codesandbox.

Answer (score 14):

And here the Typescript version when you write properties:

```
  const mapped = Children.map(children, (child, index) => {
    if(React.isValidElement(child)) {
      return React.cloneElement(child, {
        ...child.props,
        isFirst: index === 0,
        isLast: !Array.isArray(children) || index === children.length - 1,
      })
    }
    return null
  })
```

Comment: Thats the tricks with TS, you have to make sure the child is valid to prevent errors

Answer (score 13):

I think this solution is the simplest for wrap every child. When the children are rendered, you receive an instance of the component, not the component function. And you just need to wrap the instance into the wrapper component as shown below.

```
this.props.children.map(child => <Wrapper>{child}</Wrapper> )
```

For TypeScript:

```
React.Children.map(props.children, child => {
  return <Wrapper>{child}</Wrapper>
})
```

Comment: This does not work in Typescript (children prop is inferred as `React.ReactNode` which is not an array

Comment: @malikbagwala I have added option for TS

Comment: When I tried something like your first example, it failed in JS when the component has a single child. `props.children` is only an array when there is more than one child, apparently [to save an array allocation](https://zhenyong.github.io/react/tips/children-props-type.html). `React.children.map` exists because of this "[opaque data structure](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildren)," and your second example should work in JS.

Answer (score 3):

Another variant for TypeScript which I think is clean:

```
const ChildrenWithProps = Children.map(children, child =>
    cloneElement(child as JSX.Element, props),
)
```

used like:

```
return (
  <div>
    {ChildrenWithProps}
  </div>
);
```

Of course, you need to know beforehand that what is passed as `children` definitely will be a valid child element, or you need to check it with isValidElement as previous answers suggested.