# React composition - How to call parent method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm using composition in React and would like to call a parent method. All of the examples I've found use inheritance.

**Container component - Inserts a child component**

```
interface ContainerProps {
  children: ReactNode;
}

function Container(props: ContainerProps) {
  const [showApply, setShowApply] = useState<boolean>(false);

  return (
    <>
        <div>Children</div>
        {props.children}
    </>
  );

  // I want to call this method from the `children`
  function calledByChild(){}
}
```

**Composition - Needs to call `Container` method when button is clicked**

```
function CombinedComponent() {
    
    return <Container handleApplyClicked={handleApplyClicked}>
        <Button type="primary" shape="round" onClick={tellContainerThatButtonWasClicked}>
    </Container >
}
```

When the button is clicked in the `CombinedComponent` I would like it to inform the `Container`. The examples I've seen use inheritance and pass the parents method to the child but in this case the child is defining the parent within it.

How can this be achieved?

**Update**

I've tried adding this to the parent but the child components don't seem to have the extra property added.

```
{React.cloneElement(props.children as React.ReactElement<any>, { onClick: myFunc })}
```

Child interface/props

```
interface CombinedComponentProps{
  // This value is always undefined
  onClick?: () => void;
} 


function CombinedComponent(props: CombinedComponentProps) {
    ...
    // Undefined
    console.log(props.onClick)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I recently had to do something similar and, inspired by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49497934/14201528), I ended up with:

```js
const WrapperComponent = ({ children }) => {
  const myFunc = React.useCallback(() => {
    // ...
  }, []);
  
  return React.Children.map(children, (child) => {
    if (React.isValidElement(child)) {
      return React.cloneElement(child, { onClick: myFunc });
    }
  });
}
```

#### [edit] a working demo:

The following snippet demonstrate how the above approach could be used to read a child prop from the wrapper/parent component.
Please be aware that it might take a few seconds for the snippet to load and run; I did not investigate the reason for this, as it is out of the scope for the question.

```js
const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>MyApp</h1>
      <WrapperComponent>
        <button id='btn1'>btn1</button>
        <button id='btn2'>btn2</button>
        <button id='btn3'>btn3</button>
        <div className='fakeBtn' id='div1'>div1</div>
      </WrapperComponent>
    </div>
  );
}

const WrapperComponent = ({ children }) => {
  const [clickedChildId, setClickedChildId] = React.useState();
  
  const myFunc = React.useCallback((id) => {
    setClickedChildId(id)
  }, [setClickedChildId]);
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    clickedChildId && console.log(`the clicked child ID is ${clickedChildId}`);
  }, [clickedChildId]);
  
  return React.Children.map(children, (child) => {
    if (React.isValidElement(child)) {
      return React.cloneElement(child, { onClick: () => myFunc(child.props.id) });
    }
  });
  
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('#mountNode'))
```

```css
div.fakeBtn {
  background-color: #cdf;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 3px 0;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id='mountNode'></div>
```

Comment: This looks like exactly what I need. I've tried using this but the property doesn't seem to get passed through to the child. I've updated the question as I'm assuming it will be something obvious I'm missing.

Comment: Well, if you need to pass some value "up", `myFunc` can accept an argument and use it to set the state in the parent.

Comment: What I mean is `onClick` is undefined in the child component after using `cloneElement`.

Comment: My Apologies, I forgot the `return` before `React.cloneElement(...)`; I added it, now.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by cloning the children, and giving it the props that you want:

```
React.cloneElement(children, {calledByChild})
```

This way, you add the function `calledByChild` to the children, so you can call it from the children component.

It could look like this:

```
const Parent = ({ children }) => {
  const func = () => console.log("click in Parent");
  return (
    <>
      <div>children</div>
      {cloneElement(children, {func})}
    </>
  );
};

const Children = ({func}) => {
  return <button onClick={func}>Click</button>;
};
```

Take a look at this [article](https://atomizedobjects.com/blog/quick-fixes/how-to-pass-props-to-children-in-react/)

Comment: This makes sense thank you! Would you say that having to use this approach is a sign that I shouldn't be structuring my components like this or is composition like this often used?

Comment: I would not recommend to do like this. But actually it depends your needs. Can you show where do you instantiate the parent component please?

Comment: You can have a look at the documentation https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html
Usually, you give directly the children to the parent, so you can give the props to the children directly, without having to use this "hack"