# React Native how to change last collapsed elements style

Tags: reactjs, react-native, styles

If the last collapsed item is opened its bottom border should be removed, but all the other collapsable components should have a bottom border. How can i remove the bottom border of the last of type element? In React i could use `:last-of-type` but how to achieve this with React Native?
**Summary** : How to change style of last collapsed item, without using any third party library?

[image: remove border]

```
   export function Dropdown() {
    return <View>{children}</View>;
}
export function ColapseItem() {
    const [isCollapsed, setIsCollapsed] = React.useState(collapsedByDefault ?? true);

    function onToggle() {
        setIsCollapsed((isCollapsed) => !isCollapsed);
    }

    return (
        <View>
            <Pressable style={itemStyles.container} onPress={onToggle}>
                <Text>{title}</Text>
                    <Icon size={14} name='icon1' />
            </Pressable>
            {!isCollapsed && <View style={itemStyles.collapsibleItem}>{children}</View>}
        </View>
    );
}

const itemStyles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        justifyContent: "space-between",
        flexDirection: "row",
        borderBottomWidth: 1,
        borderBottomColor: 'red'
        paddingVertical: 20,
    },
    collapsibleItem: {
        paddingVertical: 20,
    },

});
```

**children file**

```
   <ColapseItem title="Label">
      <Text>children</Text>
   </ColapseItem>

   <ColapseItem title="Label">
      <Text>children</Text>
   </ColapseItem>

   <ColapseItem title="Label">
      <Text>children</Text>
   </ColapseItem>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `React.Children.map` and `React.cloneElemen`t API's.
With `React.Children.map` you can find the index of the child you want to add something. With `React.clonElement` you can copy this child and add style to it.

I also found a similar problem on: stackoverflow [React: Mapping children of a parent component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49496906/react-mapping-children-of-a-parent-component)

Remember that you need to get to the  Text child  that is in the ColapseItem child.